# Why does this blocking method prevent the css being changed?

Tags: javascript, blocking

```
function sleep(milliSeconds){
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();                    // get the current time
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds); // hog cpu until time's up
}

var busyCount = 0;    
function setBusy(bool){

    busyCount += (bool)? 1 : -1;

    $('body').css('cursor', (busyCount > 0 ) ? 'wait':'auto');

}    

function blockingMethod(){
    setBusy(true);
    //css doesn't change inbeweeen here. 
    console.log("starting blocking method");
    sleep(5000);
    console.log("blocking complete");


    setBusy(false);
}

function asyncMethod(){
    setBusy(true);
    console.log("starting async method");
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("async complete");
        setBusy(false);
    },5000);

}
```

I'm trying to simulate a code-smell problem I'm having, and to do so I need to show the code style of blocking and non-blocking methods.

The asyncMethod works fine. The problem is that the blocking method appears to move on to the sleep function before updating the mouse cursor.

Why is it doing this, and how would I work around it?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLfza9vs/

Comment: The CSS *does* change. It's just that the browser chooses not to render while your script is not yet done. The solution is simple: Use the asynchronous method.

Comment: The browser runs JS and screen repaints in the same thread, and doesn't do any screen repaints till the currently executing JS functions finish. Which makes sense, because if a single JS function changed the DOM several times it would be inefficient to repaint several times rather than once after the function completes.

Comment: @Bergi Some of the library calls I'm using are blocking. This is a mock up to demonstrate the general issue.

Comment: @Bergi how do you know that the CSS is being changed but the browser is not repainting? Is that just standard scripting behavior?

Comment: @dwjohnston: And the general solution is to use asynchronous methods for things that take (too) long. If the lib doesn't support an asynchronous variant, you can help yourself with `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Adjit: Yes, this is standard behaviour (the browser doesn't want to repaint for every single change to the DOM). And you easily check that the CSS is changed by retrieving it from the DOM.

Comment: @Bergi so now if you use something like `setTimeout` how can that help you in this situation?

Comment: @Bergi - Wrapping the `sleep` and `setBusy(false)` call in a setTimeout doesn't appear to solve this - care to post a solution?

Comment: I mean [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/nLfza9vs/3/) - doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Bergi - You mean that does work for you? This is possibly a browser issue, I'm using Firefox 11. :-/

Comment: Yes, this is definitely different in different browsers, which have different approaches at rendering&painting. In Opera 12, all three work, in my Firefox 44 only the "async" one works and "nonblocking" works when you increase the timeout (at ~20 it's inconsistent, at ~50 it works always for me).